# Actuator's Value and Message Sensor's Subject

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

Could I associate actuator's value with message sensor's subject?

I need, when I receive a message, to convert its subject in my actuator's value.

What I've tried:

[image]

Python controller's code:

```
import bge

def add_score():
    cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
    score = cont.owner
    player = score.name

    for sensor in cont.sensors:
        for body in sensor.bodies:
            for subject in sensor.subjects:

                try:
                    point = int(subject)
                except ValueError:
                    point = 0

                if player not in score: #it starts score
                    start(score, player)

                score[player] += point

                act = score.actuators['text1']
                act.value = str(score[player])

def start(score, pl):
    score[pl] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your trying to overcomplicate things. The property actuator changes a value which you can do in python by setting the property yourself.

```
score['Text'] = score[player]
```